# How to mute unknown number of youtube videos embeded through youtube iframe API (using PHP and Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-iframe-api

I have a page with youtube iframes dynamically being created. all of them are auto-played. I need to mute them all. the code I currently have mutes only the first iframe. How to modify this code to mute all of the iframes? remember iframe IDs are being created dynamically.

```
<?php foreach ($homeListings as $j => $listing) :?>

   <?php if (!empty($listing['Listing']['youtube_code'])) : ?>

       <div class="customer">

          <iframe class="muteVideo" id="<?= $listing['Listing']['youtube_code'] ?>" 
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?=$listing['Listing']['youtube_code']?>
            ?playlist=<?= $listing['Listing']['youtube_code'] ?>&autoplay=1&loop=1&
            enablejsapi=1&rel=0&">
          </iframe>


          <script>

               var tag = document.createElement('script');

               tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
               var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
               firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


               var player;

               function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                  player = new YT.Player('<?= $listing['Listing']['youtube_code'] ?>', {
                       events: {
                           'onReady': onPlayerReady
                       }
                  });
               }

               function onPlayerReady(event) {
                   player.mute();
                   player.playVideo();
               }

           </script>


        </div>
   <?php else : ?>
            <!-- do something else -->
   <?php endif; ?>

<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: put onPlayerReady() inside of onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()

Comment: @dandavis Moving onPlayerReady inside of onYouTubeIframeAPIReady didn't solve the problem. I feel the problematic part is the tag part (firstScriptTag variable).